# Error of variable undefined when the variable is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This code has worked for 6 months, then all of a sudden it started throwing this code. It is for a Tumblr theme that we had to create a work around for an issue with iframe youtube videos.

The line that is apparently throwing the error is:

```
if(theVidURL.indexOf('youtu.be') >= 0)
```

Error: TypeError: theVidURL is undefined

Here is the rest of the code:

```
function replaceThumbnailImg(){
    // var classes = $('article.video').attr('class').split(' ');
        articles = $('article.video');
        articles.each(function(){

            var headers = $(this).find('header');
            var theVidURL = $(this).find('.source_link').attr('href');

            var theVidURLArray = null;

            if(theVidURL.indexOf('youtu.be') >= 0){
                theVidURLArray = theVidURL.split('.be/');
                if(typeof theVidURLArray[1]!='undefined'){theVidURLArray = theVidURLArray[1].split('/');}

            } else {
                theVidURLArray = theVidURL.split('v=');

                if(typeof theVidURLArray[1]!='undefined'){theVidURLArray = theVidURLArray[1].split('&');}
                    theVidURLArray = theVidURLArray[0].split('?');
                }
        if(theVidURL.indexOf('youtu') >= 0){ 
            headers.each(function(){
                    theThumbURL = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+theVidURLArray[0]+'/0.jpg';

                    $(this).html('<img src="'+theThumbURL+'" />');
                });
        }
            // $('header').html('');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Seems like it's `$(this).find('.source_link')` that's not returning anything?

Comment: Your indenting is really awful. Please fix it.

Comment: Did the structure of the page change due to a Tumblr update?  Seems like $(this).find('.source_link').attr('href') is no longer the right query.

Comment: what is article...is that a tag??

Comment: So if its a tumbler theme mb you could link that site because the problem is exactly what Explosion Pills says. So you need to modify either the selector or something, but that information is on that thumbler page...

Comment: The tumblr page is http://collinsacademy.undroppable.com/

Comment: Where is your jQuery coming from and what version?  If it "suddenly" stopped working, I suspect that your jQuery version was updated without your realization that it would break anything.